# Music playback: Enter the music address from the Array and type in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick

Good day. I have a music list that, among the available features, I just want to allow the user to play and pause the music, but I encountered a problem. `onClick` I have to write a function based on the error I got earlier and I can not write `item.url.play()` directly, but if I write with function, it will not recognize the item. What is the solution now? You say.

To better understand the codes

```js
 const Musics = [
        {
            name: "это ли счастье",
            img: этолисчастьеImg,
            singer: "Rauf & Faik",
            url: этолисчастьеMusic
        },
        
        //code...
    ];

return (
        <>
            <Box className="list-box">
                {Musics.map((item) =>
                    <Grid container className="box-music">
                        <Grid item lg={3}>
                            <img src={item.img} width="80px" height="80px" className="img-box" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={7} className="text">
                            <Typography>
                                <h5 className="name"> {item.name} </h5>
                            </Typography>
                            <p style={{ color: "#6f009b" }}>{item.singer}</p>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={1}>
                            <i className="fa fa-play fa-1x pley" aria-hidden="true" onClick={x}></i>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                )}
            </Box>
        </>
    );
```

Comment: Well, you need an `audio` element to play the music, unless you have a function that plays music that you haven't told us about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use an **audio element**, then on your `onClick`, you should change the source of audio based on the URL of the song.

first put this on your DOM:

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
  Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
```

then in your html:

```
    <Grid item lg={1}>
       <i className="fa fa-play fa-1x pley" aria-hidden="true" onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); this.play(item.url);}}></i>
    </Grid>
```

and declare your play method like this:

```
play(songUrl) {
  const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
  source.src = songUrl;
  audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
  audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of x try

() => yourfunc(item)

You have access to item without calling it directly